# Can I set different type of loading animation in echarts

Tags: animation, django-rest-framework, loading, echarts

Currently I am calling an API to populate data in the bar chart made using echarts, I used the following code.
`var mychart = echarts.init(document.getElementById("test"));`
`mychart.showLoading();`
Once the data comes then I hide the loading, but in echarts I am getting only the circular shape loading option, can I use vertical bars for showing loading animation in echarts.

Answer (score 1):

Try the DOC

https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#echartsInstance.showLoading

```
default: {
    text: 'loading',color: '#c23531',
    textColor: '#000',
    maskColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)',
    zlevel: 0,
    // Font size. Available since `v4.8.0`.
    fontSize: 12,
    // Show an animated "spinner" or not. Available since v4.8.0`.
    showSpinner: true,
    // Radius of the "spinner". Available since `v4.8.0`.
    spinnerRadius: 10,
    // Line width of the "spinner". Available since `v4.8.0`.
    lineWidth: 5
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Echarts has no another loading spinner but you can make own or take any spinner lib (for [example](https://github.com/yangshun/awesome-spinners)) and place above. Of course you can use the custom series or graphic and draw something but is not quite right spent time because it's loader and its role just to show that chart is not dead and will continue action soon to prevent user leaving.